# WordPress plugin development : How to upload a file to the default "uploads" directory?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm trying to upload files to the default "wp-content/uploads" directory. Have tried almost all the available tags, still not working.

Few of the codes I tried:

1. `$filename = $_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"];`
   $tempname = $_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"];

   $folder= 'wp_upload_dir()'. $filename; *//This code is uploading the file to the "wp-admin" directory*

   if(move_uploaded_file($tempname, $folder)){$response}
2. `$uploaddir = 'uploads/';` $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $filename;`

   `if(move_uploaded_file($tempname, $uploadfile))`

`

Comment: You can use wp_upload_dir(). For more information please check this url
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/

Comment: Tried using it, it is uploading the file in the "wp-admin" folder and not "wp-content/uploads' directory.

Comment: `$folder= 'wp_upload_dir()'. $filename;` makes no sense - first of all, that’s not actually a function call, this is _text_ - I doubt you have a folder that actually has the _literal name_ `wp_upload_dir()`. And second, `wp_upload_dir` returns an _array_. You need to pick the appropriate element out of that array, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/#return

Comment: Yes, I don't have a folder with the name "wp_upload_dir()". The exact issue I'm facing is, that the function "wp_upload_dir()" is uploading the file to 'wp-admin' directory and not to the 'wp-content/uploads'. Have tried and tested a couple of other functions too, none could upload it to the desired uploads directory.

Thanks for such a prompt and detailed reply.

Answer (score 0):

I've coded to save the image in uploads folder for one of my website. please check if this code helps

```
//taking image in $name_icon
$name_icon = $_POST['myfile'];
    
    // WordPress environment
                    require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../wp-load.php' );
                     
                    $wordpress_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
             
                    $i = 1; // number of tries when the file with the same name is already exists
                     
                    $profilepicture = $_FILES['myfile'];
                    $new_file_path = $wordpress_upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $profilepicture['name'];
                    $new_file_mime = mime_content_type( $profilepicture['tmp_name'] );
                     
                    if( empty( $profilepicture ) )
                        die();
                     
                    if( $profilepicture['error'] )
                        die( $profilepicture['error'] );
                     
                    if( $profilepicture['size'] > wp_max_upload_size() )
                        die( 'It is too large than expected.' );
                     
                    if( !in_array( $new_file_mime, get_allowed_mime_types() ) )
                        die( 'WordPress doesn\'t allow this type of uploads.' );
                     
                    while( file_exists( $new_file_path ) ) {
                        $i++;
                        $new_file_path = $wordpress_upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $i . '_' . $profilepicture['name'];
                    }
                     
                    // looks like everything is OK
                    if( move_uploaded_file( $profilepicture['tmp_name'], $new_file_path ) ) {
                     
                        $upload_id = wp_insert_attachment( array(
                            'guid'           => $new_file_path, 
                            'post_mime_type' => $new_file_mime,
                            'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', $profilepicture['name'] ),
                            'post_content'   => '',
                            'post_status'    => 'inherit'
                        ), $new_file_path );
                     
                        // wp_generate_attachment_metadata() won't work if you do not include this file
                        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
                     
                        // Generate and save the attachment metas into the database
                        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $upload_id, wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $upload_id, $new_file_path ) );
```

Tested & works

Comment: The exact issue I'm facing is that the function "wp_upload_dir()" is uploading the files in "wp-admin" directory. Have tried and tested different codes too, none could upload it to "wp-content/upload" directory. 

Thank you such a prompt and detailed reply.

Comment: ok thanks for the update.
can you please define the uploads path in wp-config.php & check.
define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/uploads' );
not sure if it works but give it a try

Comment: Gave it another try, once again. Didn't work. Still uploading to the 'wp-admin' directory.

Comment: can't tell unless i see the full code because by default wp_upload_dir() will upload in uploads folder unless different path is defined

Comment: what part of code should I exactly share or give a thought to? Surely, I didn't specify any other directory.